# Issue with scaffolding a MySql database with EF Core - Method not found: Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to scaffold a MySql Database code first using `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` on .NET Core 3.1 in Visual Studio 2019. However, I keep getting the following error:

> Method not found: 'Void
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping..ctor(System.String,
> System.Type, System.Nullable`1<System.Data.DbType>, Boolean, System.Nullable`1)'.

I looked at the source code for EF Core on GitHub and I can't find a method that matches that signature - am I missing something?

My scaffold code is:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Database=database;Uid=myuid;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -o Solution --project Solution.Project.Namespace
```

I also tried

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Database=database;Uid=myuid;" MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -o Solution --project Solution.Project.Namespace
```

And I tried running both of these commands via the Developer PowerShell and the Package Manager Console. Same result.

And my DbContext is

```cs
using Solution.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore; // I tried using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore as well
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Solution.Backend
{
    public class SolutionDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JournalComment> JournalComments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("Server=localhost;Database=database;Uid=myuid;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

My DbContext code is in a project called *Solution*.Backend and my models are in a project called *Solution*.Data

I get the same result if I comment out all the `DbSet`s and try to run it without anything in the DbContext other than the `OnConfiguring` and `OnModelCreating` code. Am I missing something obvious or is there something I'm missing, or is this a known bug? I haven't found anything regarding this specific issue online anywhere. I'd appreciate some help here! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct namespace.  Namespaces are equivalent to Folder names and the classes are equivalent to filenames.  VS when you have a unique class name it will automatically be found by the compiler.  When you have duplicate class names you have to specify the full namespace and class name.

Comment: Could you be more specific - which namespace is the issue? In ```dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Database=database;Uid=myuid;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -o *Solution* --project *Solution.Project.Namespace*``` I tried changing to -o *Solution*.*Project*.*Namespace* but it gave me the same issue.

Comment: Change in code.  I would look similar to following  : Solution.Data.Solution.Backend.SolutionDBContext.Users

Answer (score 27, accepted):

MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.22 is only compatible with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1. Downgrade all Microsoft.EntityFramework packages from 5.0.0 to 3.1.10 to fix the error.

With the release of MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.23 on 18 Jan 2021, Oracle has now released a different NuGet package that's compatible with Microsoft.EntityFramework 5.0: [MySql.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore/).

See the [table of version compatibility here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html).

Alternatively, you can try switching to [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0-alpha.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/5.0.0-alpha.2) (or later); see its [table of compatible package versions](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#dependencies).

Comment: I've suffered two days for this problem. You saved my life.

Comment: This did the trick: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -version 3.1.10

Comment: Is there any other way apart from downgrading the entity framework because I really cant move away from 5.0.0???

Comment: @KingKongBigBong Yes, switch to the `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` package instead.